# How to print out the row before a specific row in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df with incidents and I would like to print out the warning that came **before** each incident. I have a way to identify incidents in the df but I need a way to loop through the whole df and print the row before each incident along with the incident itself.

for ex:

```
A                B         
warning      2018-11-01
incident     2018-10-31
warning      2018-10-30
warning      2018-10-29
warning      2018-10-28
incident     2018-10-27
```

In this case i would need to print out

warning    2018-11-01

incident   2018-10-31

and

warning    2018-10-28

incident   2018-10-27

Comment: You could have the condition to look for "incidents" then find the index of that -1 to print. You would use ```print(df.loc[[index]])```

Comment: Are there ever two incidents back-to-back?

Comment: sorry the number after means nothing

Comment: @It_is_Chris there cannot be its simply just printing row(i) and row(i-1) I'm just not familiar with the syntax to loop through

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that incidents cannot occur back-to-back then just use boolean indexing to look for incidents and the row above the indecent

```
df[(df['A'] == 'incident') | (df['A'] == 'incident').shift(-1)]

          A           B
0   warning  2018-11-01
1  incident  2018-10-31
4   warning  2018-10-28
5  incident  2018-10-27
```